# Question regarding multidimensional integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, special-functions

I would like to compute the following iterated integral in 3 dimesions:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty \left|\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(y)f(y-t)e^{-i 2 \pi t \xi} dy\right|dt d\xi
$$
where $f$ is the spheroidal wave function which I can sample at arbitrary points using SpheroidalPS[].

The absolute value in the inner integral is the cause of the problem. What is 
the way of using NIntegrate to handle this absolute value for multiple integrals.

**EDIT** The requested code gives warnings

```
NIntegrate[Abs[NIntegrate[
 SpheroidalPS[0, 0, Pi, y] SpheroidalPS[0, 0, Pi, y - t] Exp[-I 2 Pi t e], 
 {y, -Infinity, Infinity}]], {t, -Infinity, Infinity},
  {e, -Infinity, Infinity}]

 (*NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand ((-I) \[Infinity]) SpheroidalPS[0,0,\ 
 [Pi],y] SpheroidalPS[0,0,\[Pi],-\[Infinity]] has evaluated to non-numerical 
 values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{-\ 
 [Infinity],0.}}.*)
```

Comment: Show us the code you used

Comment: Hi Iconoclast, after asking 8 questions in Mathematica.SE you should know that here its considered helpful and polite show your own efforts and share your data and code attempts in a well [formatted form](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX), so we can quickly see the problem you are facing. Please help us to help you and [edit your question](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX) accordingly. Also, it's never too late to take the [tour].

Comment: It looks a lot like the Fourier transform of a convolution.

Comment: @rhermans I have added the code.

Comment: @bill s its the L1 norm of the STFT (Short Time Fourier Transform) of a prolate with respect to the same prolate as a test function.

Comment: You can start with: `f[t_?NumericQ, e_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[
  SpheroidalPS[0, 0, Pi, y] SpheroidalPS[0, 0, Pi, 
    y - t] Exp[-I 2 Pi t e], {y, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
  Method -> "MonteCarlo", MaxPoints -> 20]; NIntegrate[
 Abs[f[t, e]], {t, -Infinity, Infinity}, {e, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
 Method -> "MonteCarlo", MaxPoints -> 20]` ,but my hardware is to SSLOW. Increase `MaxPoints->10000` or more for a more accurate result.

Comment: thnx already doing that.